# Powershell Tables & Counts

Tags: powershell

The Command [Get-RDUserSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/remotedesktop/get-rdusersession?view=winserver2012r2-ps) gives me a Perfekt view of Connected Users by Server an even the Session State.
But i would like to Group those Outputs in a new Variable

What i like would be an Output

```
ServerName(this Should be Unieque)|TotalAmmountofConnected Users witch is an Adition of State_Active,State_Connected,Session_Disconnected 
|SessionState(State_Active this in Count)| SessionState(State_Connected this in Count)| SessionState(State_Disconnected this in count)
```

I have tried :

```
$Value = Get-RDUserSession -CollectionName Colection -ConnectionBroker ConnectionBroker
$Value | Group-Object -Property ServerName,SessionState | Where-Object {$_.Count} | Select Name,Count
```

I dont't know how to group those values or seperate them form each other. I would really need some help on this....

This is a Example Output:

```
ServerName                 SessionState
Server1.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server1.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server1.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server1.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server1.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server1.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server1.domain.com       STATE_CONNECTED
Server3.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server3.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server3.domain.com       STATE_DISCONNECTED
Server3.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server3.domain.com       STATE_CONNECTED
Server3.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server3.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server2.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server2.domain.com       STATE_CONNECTED
Server2.domain.com       STATE_CONNECTED
Server2.domain.com       STATE_CONNECTED
Server2.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server7.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server7.domain.com       STATE_ACTIVE
Server7.domain.com       STATE_DISCONNECTED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out counting the properties within the Group property of each group:

```
$Value = Get-RDUserSession -CollectionName Colection -ConnectionBroker ConnectionBroker
$Value | 
    sort ServerName |
    Group ServerName |
    Select Name,
        @{l='TotalUsers';       e={($_.group.SessionState).count}},
        @{l='ConnectedUsers';   e={($_.group.SessionState | where {$_ -like 'State_Active'}).count}},
        @{l='DisconnectedUsers';e={($_.group.SessionState | where {$_ -like 'State_Disconnected'}).count}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Value = Get-RDUserSession -CollectionName Colection -ConnectionBroker ConnectionBroker
$Overview = $Value | 
    sort ServerName |
    Group ServerName |
    Select Name,
        @{l='Total'; e={($_.group.SessionState).count}},
        @{l='State_Active'; e={($_.group.SessionState | where {$_ -like 'State_Active'}).count}},
        @{l='State_Connected';e={($_.group.SessionState | where {$_ -like 'State_Connected'}).count}},
        @{l='State_Disconnected';e={($_.group.SessionState | where {$_ -like 'State_Disconnected'}).count}}

$overview | ft -AutoSize
```

THANKS!